# Is it possible to call the JIT debugger window from a c# program?

Tags: c#, debugging

I was wondering if it was possible via a line of code in C# program to interrupt the execution of the program and make appear the window which allows you to select a debugger to start debugging.

Anthony

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
if( System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached )
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break ();
else
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch ();
```

Comment: @JonB: sorry totally forgot !